# Inherit extended generic type from an interface

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm worried I've phrased this question wrongly, so here is an example to illustrate:

I have an interface:

```
public interface ICard  extends Comparable<T>{

    public abstract String toString();

    public abstract int compareTo(T o) throws WrongCardTypeException;

}
```

What I want is that the class implementing ICard automagically implements `Comparable<T>` so that you can only compare whatever class implements ICard

Instead I need to specify the generic for the comparable extension and use the sort of `instancof` check below

```
public interface ICard  extends Comparable<ICard>{

    public abstract String toString();

    public abstract int compareTo(ICard o) throws WrongCardTypeException;

}

public class PlayingCard implements ICard{
    public enum Rank { TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
        SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE }

    public enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES }

    private  Rank rank;
    private  Suit suit;

    public PlayingCard(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() { return rank; }

    public Suit getSuit() { return suit; }


    @Override
    public String toString() { return rank + " of " + suit; }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ICard o) throws WrongCardTypeException {
        if (o instanceof PlayingCard){
        PlayingCard c = (PlayingCard)o;
        int rankCompare = rank.compareTo(c.rank);
        return rankCompare != 0 ? rankCompare : suit.compareTo(c.suit);
        }
    throw new WrongCardTypeException("Tried to compare "+o.getClass().getCanonicalName()+" to "+ this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
```

I was wondering if there was a neater way to do this that would let me do away with the the `instanceof` check? Wildcards? I'm not sure here. Or is the `instanceof` check ok? I've heard it has 'code smell', e.g. was bad practice.

---

I have a similar (?) issue with my IDeck interface:

```
public interface IDeck<T extends ICard> extends Comparable<T>, Collection<T>{
    public ArrayList<T> getDeck();
    public void setDeck(Set<T> newDeck);
}
```

In the class that implements this, my `compareTo` method takes parameters of type `ICard`, though I want to compare decks that inherit from IDeck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your `ICard` interface generic, with a bound, so it any generic type parameter must itself be an `ICard`.

```
public interface ICard<T extends ICard<T>>  extends Comparable<T>{
```

Then you can specify `PlayingCard` in the `ICard` interface in the `PlayingCard` class:

```
public class PlayingCard implements ICard<PlayingCard> {
```

Comment: Could you talk me over why I want `ICard<T extends ICard<T>>` ? I think I get the wildcard use, but I've only ever seen generics for collection, and the fact that cards aren't a collection of card is throwing me off. Further mor how can I extend this to a Deck interface, that can only contain a certain kind of card?

Comment: You stated that whatever class implements `ICard` could only compare "whatever class implements ICard", hence the bound.  Generics are for when a class has a specific yet unknown relationship with another class.  In collections, that relationship is "contains", but in your case it's "is comparable to".  A `Deck` class sounds like a collection of cards, so like a collections class, you may want something like `public interface Deck<T extends ICard<T>>`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that interface specification for my `IDeck` but when I extend Comparable in that, I get this method outline: `public int compareTo(PlayingCard o)` when I want `public int compareTo(PlayingCardDeck o)`. In guess that's worth a second question though.

Comment: The `T extends ICard<T>` is completely pointless from a type safety point of view.

Comment: @newacct Would you care to explain why it's pointless?  The point is that it satisfies the requirement that "What I want is that the class implementing ICard automagically implements Comparable<T> _so that you can only compare whatever class implements ICard_". (emphasis mine)

Comment: @rgettman: okay, so I have `class Foo implements ICard<Foo>`, and `class Bar implements ICard<Foo>`. How does that satisfy that requirement? Plus generics is not for making arbitrary "requirements"; only ones that are useful for avoiding casts.

Comment: @newacct if you had `class PlayingCards implements ICard<PlayingCards> ` and `class ShineyPlayingCards implements ICard<PlayingCards> `....that should still be valid, at lease from the logic I'm applying. And should allow *safe* use of, for instance `(PlayingCards)myShineyPlayingCards.compareTo(myPlayingCards)`. Right?

Comment: @Pureferret: and if you declared it as `public interface ICard<T>  extends Comparable<T>` then everything would still be the same

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
public interface ICard<T> extends Comparable<T>{

  public abstract String toString();

  public abstract int compareTo(T o) throws WrongCardTypeException;

}
```

(note the `ICard<T>`)

and then `PlayingCard implements ICard<PlayingCard>`.

That said, this interface gets you exactly nothing over the `Comparable` interface, since `toString()` is already available for all Java objects, and trying to require it will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "re-specify" T, try with:

```
public interface ICard<T> extends Comparable<T>
```